# How to notify the trigger of Web scenario from Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, zabbix

For other triggers Slack notification is done without problems,
Regarding triggers from the Web scenario, trouble occurrence is not notified to Slack 
 even if it is displayed on Zabbix's dashboard, so we are in trouble.
I also can not find a log of failure in particular.

[Environmental setting]
Agent installed on server
zabbix 4.0.1

[Web Scenario Setting]

■ Scenario 
Name: Top page normal display check
Application: HTTP service
Agent: Zabbix

■ Step
Name: Hogehoge
URL: hogehoge.com
Timeout 5s
Request character string apple/apple/apple
Request status code 200

---

[Event]
Dashboard screen display

action
Message / Command -> Slack
Status -> Sent

I would be pleased if you could tell me where to check.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that user, which you are gonna alert, has at least Read rights for group, where host with web scenario placed. In other cases there will be no alerts.